# about unit test practice?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

Now I have some question of unit test?

#### Business

> when order should display some available coupon list

#### Code

```
public List<Coupon> getAvailableCouponsWhenOrder(String productCategory, int productPrice, String shopId, String userId){
    // get all available coupons -- that is not used
    List<Coupon> couponList = couponMapper.queryCoupons(userId);
    // filter coupons
    List<Coupon> availableList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Coupon coupon : couponList) {
        // some coupon only support specific category, e.g. book, phone
        if(!checkCategory(coupon,productCategory)){
            continue;
        }
        // some coupon have use condition , e.g. full 100 then minus 50
        if(!checkPrice(coupon,productPrice)){ 
            continue;
        }
        // you cannot use other shop's coupon
        if(!checkShopCoupon(coupon,shopId)){
            continue;
        }

        availableList.add(coupon);
    }

    return availableList;
}
```

And have below unit test

```
@Test
public void test_exclude_coupon_which_belong_to_other_shop(){
    String productCategory = "book";
    int productPrice = 200;
    String shopId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10); 
    String userId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);

    Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
    String anotherShopId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
    coupon.setShopId(anotherShopId); // other shop's coupon
    coupon.setCategory("book"); // only use for buying book
    coupon.setFullPrice(200); // full 200 minus 50
    coupon.setPrice(50);

    when(couponMapper.queryCoupons(userId)).thenReturn(newArrayList(coupon));

    List<Coupon> availableCoupons = service.getAvailableCoupons(productCategory, productPrice, shopId, userId);
    // check whether exclude other shop's coupon
    assertEquals(0, availableCoupons.size());
}
```

but even if it passed, I still have no confidence that it is right? because maybe previous check is failed, e.g. checkCategory always return false?

So how to know it really executed `checkShopCoupon` ?

Comment: Look at Mockito.verify

Comment: but these check method both are inner private method of this service class, how to use verify?

Comment: You just need more unit tests. Anything which has control logic like that is going to need multiple unit tests to exercise the different paths through the logic. Just add a test which passes in a coupon for which 'checkCategory()' doesn't return false. And so one for any other condition you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Please stay **away** from using a mocking framework to test your private methods. The only thing that (probably!) requires mocking is **this** line:

```
List<Coupon> couponList = couponMapper.queryCoupons(userId);
```

It is really simple: you have to make sure that your list `couponList` has a specifc content. In other words: you create a whole set of different test methods that each pre-sets `couponList` with different values. And then you check that the list returned matches your expectations.

And for the record: better use the one and only assert that one really needs:

```
assertThat(service.getAvailableCoupons(productCategory, productPrice, shopId, userId), is(somePredefinedList));
```

(where *is* is a Hamcrest matcher method)

Long story short: you probably need to use mocking to gain control over the return value of that call to queryCoupons() - but that is the only part that requires mocking here!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that you need to check in the test: the logic is correct and that the logic is invoked correctly. In your case it can be:

- A test to check the logic: `CouponMapperTest#queryingCouponReturnsCouponByUserId()`
- To check whether it's actually invoked you create a component test (without a mock) that invokes `getAvailableCouponsWhenOrder()` which in turn invokes `couponMapper.queryCoupons(userId)`

But with the suggested approach there is a risk that you end up with a lot of component tests which could take time to run. To fight with that you need to build a balanced Test Pyramid ([here is a thorough example](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html)) to ensure that you have a lot of unit tests, fewer component tests and even fewer of system tests. Some advise on that:

- Move towards OOP if possible. That means ObjectA contains ObjectB as opposed to containing IdOfObjectB. That would allow you to move logic lower to the domain objects. Which leads to the..
- Move domain logic as low as possible (preferably to the domain model where it actually belongs). A.k.a. Rich Model. Then you'll be able to test things without initializing half of the app. And that's faster.

Mocking frameworks add a lot of burden to maintain your tests. If something is refactored you often have to change a whole bunch of tests. Another problem with the mocking frameworks - you test things in isolation while you have to also ensure that the project works as a whole.

So I'd discourage the usage of mocking unless it's a boundary of your app or it's a very heavy dependency.